# Python and Excel: convert an If function from excel to Python

Tags: python, excel, if-statement

I have an IF function from excel which looks like this:

```
=WENN('Efficiency Wages'!B2>'Living Wages'!B2;'Efficiency Wages'!B2;"")
```

("Wenn" means "if" - its german)

So basically if a value of B2 from sheet "Efficiency Wages" is higher than the value of B2 from sheet "Living Wages" then value should be the B2 value from Efficiency Wages. If not than then the cell should be blank. This function is written in another sheet called "new sheet".

My problem: how can i write this IF function in Python? I know that I can start with this:

```
if ws2.cell(row=2, column= 2).value > ws1.cell(row=2, column= 2).value:
    ws3.cell(row=2, column= 2).value = ws2.cell(row=2, column= 2).value
```

But i dont only want the function for cell B2. It should be a loop because this function goes for 12 columns and 52 rows.

Comment: What interface package are you using ?

Comment: sorry, i am new to python (or programming at all) what exactly is an interface package? The packages i have installed are openpyxl, pandas, numpy and xlwings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like :

```
for numRow in range(firstRow,firstRow+12+1):
    for numCol in range(firstCol,firstCol+12+1):
        if ws2.cell(row=numRow, column= numCol).value > ws1.cell(row=numRow, column= numCol).value:
            ws3.cell(row=numRow, column= numCol).value = ws2.cell(row=numRow, column= numCol).value
        else:
            ws3.cell(row=numRow, column= numCol).value = “”
```

Comment: this is my error:  TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'. But i dont have any string values..?

Comment: Try to print value before testing to see how these are interpreted by python (strings have ‘)

Comment: Okay i see what my new problem is. It is a string because somehow Python suddenly cant read my data from Excel? If i now print df = pd.read_excel("Wages.xlsx", sheet_name="Living Wages", usecols=cols) my outputs are only NaN. But it worked before and printed out the correct values?

Comment: Did you had some formatting in your excel document?

Comment: So in excel sheet "Living Wages" B2 has for example the value "10". But it was calculated with the help of another column so if you click on B2 cell in Excel it says "=(N2/12)". If i print the whole dataframe the data is correct, but if only print B2 in python it prints  "=(N2/12)" and not 10

Comment: Try with ws2.values instead of ws2.cell.value when accessing for testing (I don’t know the exact syntax for row and col, maybe something like ws2.values[row][col] .

Comment: it doesnt seem to work, i think i will ask a new question to this topic, but i appreciate your help! the loop code works with another sheet where i dont have formulas in excel

Comment: I found [this page](https://www.it-swarm-fr.com/fr/python/lire-la-valeur-de-la-cellule-excel-et-non-la-formule-qui-la-calcule-openpyxl/1051190696/amp/) which may you.